# date() php function providing different hour if using windows or mac wamp/xamp apache server

Tags: php, apache

when I try to convert unix time using date() function in php it provides different hours when running in apache server in windows (wamp) or mac (xamp).. which is correct?? How can I make them provide the same time? (cause I need to be able to run it in both computers)

The code I'm using is:

`date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
    $time_unix = -2209136583.6412;
    $time_format = date("H:i:s", $time_unix);`

Results: mac --> 06:56:57 windows --> 13:25:13

Comment: Out of curiosity, do the computers have the same system time?

Comment: Using UNIX timestamps for dates before 1970 is not recommended, much less if it's a 64 bit integer. Most likely you're running into the integer size limitation on Windows. You should be using an ISO timestamp string, e.g. `Sat Dec 30 06:56:57 UTC 1899`.